# Quering JSON in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, spring-data-jpa

I have a table say t_records which has a JSON type column say col_json which can have value like below

```
{
  "1": {
    "value": null,
    "comment": null,
    "timestamp": null,
    "guidelineId": null,
    "pushedToSnowflakePipeline": "yes"
  },
  "2": {
    "value": null,
    "comment": null,
    "timestamp": null,
    "guidelineId": null,
    "pushedToSnowflakePipeline": "yes"
  },
  "3": {
    "value": null,
    "comment": null,
    "timestamp": null,
    "guidelineId": null,
    "pushedToSnowflakePipeline": "no"
  }
}
```

I want to query the rows which have isPushedToSnowflakePipeline=no

I tried with below query but it is not returning any records.

```
SELECT * FROM t_records WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(col_json, '$.*.pushedToSnowflakePipeline')='no';
```

Where am I going wrong with the query?

Comment: Do you have control over this JSON?  Seems like it should be using an array instead of objects keyed with number strings.

Comment: `JSON_EXTRACT(col_json, '$.*.pushedToSnowflakePipeline')` is going to return an array, as there are three values for that key: `["yes", "yes", "no"]`. For this one record of data that contains this json, do you want to filter it out if it has at least one"no"? do you want to keep it if it has at least one "yes"? What is your expected output from this query? [Check out this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1R7cx0jj) to see what's happening and why your `='no'` isn't working.

Comment: @JNevill - I want to filter it out if it has atleast one no

Comment: Got it. You can do the extract of those values out to a json array like you are currently doing and then use `json_contains()` to search that result: `WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(col_json->'$.*.pushedToSnowflakePipeline', '"no"') = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Analysis

If this is the typical `JSON` that is stored, the value that will be returned from this query is an array since we iterate over multiple keys in this case ["1","2","3"].

Your current where statement:

```
JSON_EXTRACT(col_json, '$.*.pushedToSnowflakePipeline');
```

returns, this:
`["yes", "yes", "no"]`, which it is not filtering properly when you check if this value `="no"`

### Solution

If you are wanting to check if any of these values = "no", then you need to first get the array of pushedToSnowflakePipeline and then filter that array to see if the values contained are "no".

Update your WHERE statement to this:

```
JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(assay_data, '$.*.pushedToSnowflakePipeline'), '"no"', "$") = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, your attempted `where` condition is failing because `json_extract()` is returning a json array that contains all of the keys at that wildcard path. An array can't be equal to a scalar/integer value and so you get nothing returned.

Since the requirement is to return only rows where all of the nested `pushedToSnowflakePipeline` keys are "yes", you can use function `json_contains()` on the array that is being returned by your `json_extract()` function.

Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE t_records (col_json JSON);
INSERT INTO t_records VALUES ('{
  "1": {
    "value": null,
    "comment": null,
    "timestamp": null,
    "guidelineId": null,
    "pushedToSnowflakePipeline": "yes"
  },
  "2": {
    "value": null,
    "comment": null,
    "timestamp": null,
    "guidelineId": null,
    "pushedToSnowflakePipeline": "yes"
  },
  "3": {
    "value": null,
    "comment": null,
    "timestamp": null,
    "guidelineId": null,
    "pushedToSnowflakePipeline": "no"
  }
}');
INSERT INTO t_records VALUES ('{
  "1": {
    "value": null,
    "comment": null,
    "timestamp": null,
    "guidelineId": null,
    "pushedToSnowflakePipeline": "yes"
  },
  "2": {
    "value": null,
    "comment": null,
    "timestamp": null,
    "guidelineId": null,
    "pushedToSnowflakePipeline": "yes"
  },
  "3": {
    "value": null,
    "comment": null,
    "timestamp": null,
    "guidelineId": null,
    "pushedToSnowflakePipeline": "yes"
  }
}');
```

Using `json_contains(json_col->'$.*.pushedToSnowflakePipelineh', '"no"') = 0` will filter out the records you aren't interested in. `->` is just shorthand for `json_extract()` in this case.

```
SELECT col_json->'$.*.pushedToSnowflakePipeline'
FROM t_records
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(col_json->'$.*.pushedToSnowflakePipeline', '"no"') = 0
```

---

```
col_json->'$.*.pushedToSnowflakePipeline'
-----------------------------------------
["yes", "yes", "yes"]
```

Working [dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/qsNk6W9l)